# How to search multiple words in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables the ingredient(ingredient_id,name),menu(recipe_id,ingredient_id,category_id) and recipe(recipe_id, r_name,r_description).

### ingredient_id   name

1           Onion

2             Paul
 3             Pepper

4             Oil

### recipe_id   ingredient_id   category_id

1             3                1

1             4                1

2             3                1

2             4                1

### recipe_id   r_name        r_description

1          Adobo           yummy

2         Kaldereta        yucky

What I want is if I search "Pepper, Oil" , the result should be the recipe that corresponds with the ingredients which is the adobo and kaldereta.

I had this tried but it is only static i want it dynamic and also i want to explode ingredient_name so that I could search multiple words.

```
  public function get_halal()
{
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('recipe');
    $this->db->join('menu', 'menu.recipe_id = recipe.recipe_id');
    $this->db->join('ingredient', 'ingredient.ingredient_id = menu.ingredient_id');
    $this->db->where('menu.category_id = 1');
    $this->db->like('ingredient.ingredient_name','Mango', 'both');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: Are you using [Active Record](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)? Do you have any code that you've tried but isn't quite right?

Comment: Yes @Windle I'm using active record. I've edited my question. please take a look at it.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If i understood what you want to do, give a try to this.
You need to set your $search_values, you have a string or an array ?
Supouse you have a string:

```
//$search_values = "Pepper, Oil";
public function get_halal($search_values)
{
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('recipe');
$this->db->join('menu', 'menu.recipe_id = recipe.recipe_id');
$this->db->join('ingredient', 'ingredient.ingredient_id = menu.ingredient_id');
$this->db->where('menu.category_id = 1');

if (strpos($search_values, ',') !== false) {
    $search = explode(',' , $search_values);
    $this->db->like('ingredient.ingredient_name', trim($search[0]), 'both');
    unset($search[0]);
        foreach ($search as $term){
            $this->db->or_like('ingredient.ingredient_name', trim($term), 'both');
        }
    }else{
        //this means you only have one value 
        $this->db->like('ingredient.ingredient_name',$search_values, 'both');
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

in case $search_values is an array you have to skip to the if condition directly and do the foreach.

Comment: In your or_like declarations, what does the third parameter do? I.e. 'both'.

Answer (score 0):

First u have to make the query so you can find the selected data which u have search

```
$this->db->select('recipe.r_name');
$this->db->from('recipe');
$this->db->join('menu', 'recipe.recipe_id = menu.recipe_id');
$this->db->join('ingredient' , 'ingredient.ingredient_id = menu.ingredient_id');
$this->db->where('ingredient.ingredient_id' , your search id);
$this->db->get();
```

[See the guide of codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: But how can I explode the ingredient_name so that I can search multiple words? @MoizArif

Comment: what u want to do... ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('recipe.r_name');
$this->db->from('recipe');
$this->db->join('menu', 'recipe.recipe_id = menu.recipe_id');
$this->db->join('ingredient' , 'ingredient.ingredient_id = menu.ingredient_id');
$this->db->where('ingredient.ingredient_name in (your Search Values));
$this->db->get();
```

Try This Code .this code Work fine for me